# Who are the holders of stocks on the market?

Tags: investing, stock-markets

Is there a source that documents who are the holders of stocks on the market? I am especially interested in the distribution of big players such as BlackRock, Vanguard and private investors.

I.e. 70% of the global market is owned by big players, 30% by private investors.

I think that the majority is the big players but is there any proof for that?

Any information is highly appreciated.

**Update:**

Meanwhile, I found something but I'm still interested in more sources:

https://www.businessinsider.com/who-owns-the-us-equity-market-2013-1?IR=T

Comment: How do you define "big player"?  For instance, Vanguard and other mutual fund companies "own" large amounts of stock.  Do you count them as "big players", or consider that the stocks are actually owned by the many people & institutions who invest through them?

Comment: Yes, the term "big player" is a bit vague but I am looking for the ones who can decide to buy/sell large amounts of stocks if they want to. This can be either one very rich individual or mutual fund companies.

Comment: Another type of "big player" would be institutional funds, like college endowment funds.  E.g. Harvard's fund is somewhere around $37 billion, per Google.  The larger charitable foundations would have substantial funds, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a more specific breakdown, one good source I know of is [WhaleWisdom](https://whalewisdom.com/).
They aggregate 13F filings of the institutions and you can then filter it based on either stock or institution.

To see the ownership structure of a specific stock, e.g. AMZN, you could check here:
https://whalewisdom.com/stock/amzn
(scroll down and sort by ownership)